# Finding the square root of a ring element modulo a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

Suppose I am working with polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_5$. Let $P(x)$ be some irreducible quadratic. We know that the remainders modulo $P(x)$ will form a ring of remainders.

Now suppose I wanted to find the **square root** of one of the elements in the ring say $r$. In other words, find the elements $a_i$ such that $a_i^2=r$.

Now I could very well square every single element in the ring, apply mod $P(x)$ and then observe which element maps to $r$. But this can be cumbersome especially for larger rings.

So my question is

> Is there a better way of finding the square root of an element in the ring of remainders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the fact that the ring $F = \mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(P)$ is isomorphic to the field with $25 = 5^{2}$ elements. An element $r \in F$ is a (non-zero) square iff $r^{12} = 1$ in $F$. So you first check whether this holds.

Then to find the square root of $r$ you can use [Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm#Generalizations), or other such algorithms.