# How to compute the square root of a polynomial modulo another polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, square-numbers

What is a method to find the polynomial square root modulo another polynomial, i.e. find a polynomial $r(x)$ such that

$$r(x)^2 \mod{x^3+3x+1} = -453600x^2 - 160650x - 4725$$

?

From various sources, this seems to be a computationally hard problem?

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcJImruRSyE&t=844s
2. [Finding the square root of a ring element modulo a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789105/finding-the-square-root-of-a-ring-element-modulo-a-polynomial)
3. [Does every polynomial over a finite field have a square root modulo an irreducible polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814886/does-every-polynomial-over-a-finite-field-have-a-square-root-modulo-an-irreducib)
4. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242923202_Short_Polynomial_Representations_for_Square_Roots_Modulo_p

Comment: It would be good to mention some of the "various sources" for convenience of users.

Comment: @coffeemath sure, i have added a couple related links

Comment: All those sources talk about how you can relatively straightforwardly find the roots of polynomials mod p in finite fields. That’s a different problem from what you have. Of course, you could restrict to int coefficients and take it mod p and maybe show no integer polynomials exist.

Comment: @Eric thank you. I think I found a workaround (for small enough numbers at least)... There are different parameters that give rise to valid coefficients $−453600x^2−160650x−4725$, so by optimizing for the smallest coefficients that are valid, $r(x)$ can at least be searched by force in a small range of $a,b,c$.

Comment: Note that if you evaluate the equation at the roots of the modulus, you get $r$ and the right side agreeing in value, when evaluated at the roots of the modulus. Since the degree of $r$ only needs to be smaller than the modulus, that interpolation gives you $r$. It might be possible to work modulo a large prime such that the modulus splits modulo that prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it suffices to consider degree $\leq$ 2 polynomials of the form $r(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ since anything larger can be reduced first.

Squaring $r$, reducing $\mod x^3+3x+1$, and equating your polynomial gives $3$ degree $2$ equations in $3$ variables. This can be reduced to a degree $8$ single variable polynomial through substitution which can be solved through numerical approximation (this is known as intersecting $3$ quadrics). This all isn’t computationally expensive (at least when you’re modding a degree 3 polynomial, it’s exponential in the degree), but it seems tricky to explicitly code up.

Comment: This was literally the approach I was thinking of doing as well for the same problem.  Was writing this in the General Number Field Sieve algorithm as a verification step (there are more efficient ways to avoid the polynomial square root).  But I cant for a second believe this method of squaring, reducing and equating coefficients is a good idea as higher degree polynomials make approximation even more of a problem.  If working in integers, this is pretty bad.  I would imagine SageMath would have some better way to handle this like a polynomiaal version of Tonelli Shanks.

Comment: Agreed. This post is mainly for solving the real case and disproving the claim that this is “computationally hard”.  I agree there are likely speed ups for integers.